# Accessing 'Internet Accounts' programmatically

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm trying to access the 'accounts' that are stored in the Internet Accounts area on the system settings on OSX. I'm aware of the 'ACAccount' library, but this only really seems to be of any use for Social integration, for example Facebook/Twitter, what i would like is to be able to detect that you have an Exchange account there and open up certain features within an app. But i'm guessing i'll need to get my users to re-enter their details in my app?

I did try and use it, however i get an empty array.

```
ACAccountStore *store = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
NSArray *accounts = [store accounts]; //This is empty
```

Does anyone know if i'm missing something, or if it's not possible? Thanks!

**Edit**

I have gained access to the Twitter account for example, but it's not returned in the Accounts list, i had to request permission first. Which makes sense. However, i still see no way of getting access to the Exchange account.

```
ACAccountStore *account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
ACAccountType *accountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:
                              ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

[account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil
                              completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
{
    if (granted == YES)
    {
        NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [account
                                    accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

    }
}];
```

Comment: Did you check the [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/samplecode/PrivacyPrompts/Listings/PrivacyPrompts_APLPrivacyClassesTableViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013410-PrivacyPrompts_APLPrivacyClassesTableViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6)?

Comment: I didn't see that one, but i saw similar. That just seems to confirm my theory that i can't access anything other than social?

Comment: Yeah looks that way to me too.